# I am trying to put a swiper slider inside popup (modal) but slider not work ,, on the other side i appling same code at page and work well

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal, swiper.js

I am trying to put a swiper slider inside popup (modal) but slider not work ,, on the other side i appling same code at page and work well

```
<div class="modal fade main-parttime" id="main-parttime" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">X</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    
                    
                    <div class="swiper-container">
                        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Add Pagination -->
                        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
                        <!-- Add Arrows -->
                        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
                        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                    </div>
                    
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to put the setTimeout after Bootstrap modal function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".modal").on('show.bs.modal', function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var swiper3 = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
                pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
                nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
                prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
                slidesPerView: 1,
                spaceBetween: 30,
                loop: true,
                effect: 'fade'
            });
        }, 500);
    });
});
```